# Array and foreach return Illegal string offset

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array like:

```
array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'min' => 5,
        'max' => 20,
        'unique' => 'users',
        'name' => 'Username'
    )
);
```

This array goes into a function like (this is not the complete function):

```
//$source = $_POST
public function validate($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {
                    //db->sanitize = mysqli_real_escape_string()
            $value = $this->db->sanitize($source[$item]);

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                            //The problem is here with $rule['name']
                $this->addError($rule['name'].' is empty');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I would like to use the `'name'` key from the array to display a user friendly input field name but all it returns is: Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in

Comment: Both `$rule` and `$rule_value` are strings.  They are the key/value (respectively) of your `$rules` array.  I'm guessing you want `$rules['name']`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thank you for your answer that solved it. Pretty stupid I couldn't come up with that my self tought :P

Comment: We all make silly mistakes now and then :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat if you would post it as an answer I can close the question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `$rule` and `$rule_value` are strings.  They are the key/value (respectively) of your `$rules` array.

I'm guessing you want `$rules['name']`.

```
if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
    $this->addError($rules['name'].' is empty');
}
```